# Jenkins pipeline build does not enter queue with locked resources like freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to move my jobs from freestyle to use a single pipeline from SCM, where each job has has specific parameters.

I am using Lockable Resources plugin in the freestyle jobs. This works great as the job enters the build queue and waits until resources are available:

```
(pending—Waiting for resource instances [resource1, resource2])
```

With pipeline to lock a resource lock() is used, but the job will begin running and take up an executor slot while it waits for the resource and make it impossible to have a reasonable timeout.

How can I replicate the behavior of lockable resources from freestyle job with a pipeline?

Comment: "make it impossible to have a reasonable timeout" - actually you can combine `timeout` option or step with `lock`.

Comment: To be clear the question is more about getting jobs to queue without executing, so that the resource is not used. The best way is to lock, node, timeout, but still the job is running while acquiring lock, then if the node isnt free it could be hogging resource while executor slot opens up. With freestyle jobs it seems that the build will queue based on node AND resource availability which is what I want.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm facing with the same thing